# Erro ao consultar API no Angular

Tags: api, angular, http, express.js, http-request

Bom dia, estou tentando acessar minha API pelo angular através do metódo `get`
do modulo http, os meus arquivos estão no meu [repositório](https://github.com/GateJkin/algularteste) do github caso alguém queira dar uma olhada. Estou seguindo este tutorial [aqui](https://imasters.com.br/apis/consumindo-json-via-http-no-angular-js-4/?trace=1519021197&source=single)
para fazer a requisição, porém sempre da o seguinte erro:
`ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
src/app/app.component.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/danielhgimenez/app-test/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
src/app/app.component.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/pacoteAPI'.
src/app/app.component.ts(4,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/app.service'.
src/app/app.component.ts(18,3): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'dados'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.dados'?
src/app/app.service.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/danielhgimenez/app-test/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
src/app/app.service.ts(17,14): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.`

Não sei como resolver esse problema. Aparentemente ele é causado por eu estar usando a versão mais recente do angular e precisa dessa biblioteca de compatibilidade, ou ela foi retirada na versão nova (não sei ao certo). Eu tinha "conseguido arrumar" (se é que vocês me entendem) instalando os pacotes `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` e usando o comando `npm audit fix --force` para arrumar os erros de instalação, porém mais pra frente continuou dando erro.

***Tudo o que eu preciso é fazer uma requisição get*** em um servidor localhost que devolverá um JSON, pegar os dados do json e mostrar na tela. Aceito quaisquer sugestões para solucionar o problema, e ***agradeço se alguém tiver um link com um artigo mais novo ou que ensine melhor a fazer um requisição.***

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção :)

Comment: Recentemente você atualizou seu projeto para o angular 6?

Comment: O comando `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` que você rodou era necessário, isso permite que você mantenha compatibilidade com versões anteriores a versão 6 sem precisar alterar o seu código. Onde tem `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` troca para `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`